# How to Export/Import a Data Source from DataGrip?

Tags: datasource, datagrip

I can't seem to figure out how to export a data source configuration in DataGrip (currently on 2016.2 EAP).

I would like to export a handful of data sources and share them with my teammates to make it easier for them to get up and running on DG.

I've tried `File->Export Settings` (exporting all settings) and did not notice the data source configurations within the resulting jar file.

I seem to recall that in earlier versions of the tool (when it was still called 0xDBE), you could find data source configuration files on the drive and share them that way, but I am unable to locate any at this time.

Perhaps it's not possible?

Comment: Is it possible to share passwords too? Seems to be useful for intranet dev environments where all usernames/passwords are standardized or usually grabbed from self-service systems that scan DBs

Comment: @DanSerbyn According to jebrains docs it appears you still can't include passwords outside of copy/pasting in your local workspace: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/managing-data-sources.html#group-data-sources-in-folders

Answer (score 64, accepted):

**UPDATE FROM 2021!**

Starting from version 2021.1, you can just press Ctrl/Cmd+C on the data source, and then Ctrl/Cmd+V it in another IDE. The clipboard contains XML for the data source, so you can send it to the colleague via e-mail, messenger etc.

---

It is possible!
You need to share a project with your friend — all you do in DataGrip is in the context of a project. If you did not create a new one, everything is under the default project. Look at the gif:

[image]

The more detailed information can be found in the tutorial: https://blog.jetbrains.com/datagrip/2018/05/21/copy-and-share-data-sources-in-datagrip/

Comment: Thanks @moscas !  I've accepted this answer 1) because it clearly shows how to find the root folder for any project and 2) because it turns out to be the only way I could find to share connections that also shares the login credentials of the connections.  I will be adding a follow-up comment with the rest of my findings, but thanks again for replying!

Comment: This also kind of works for importing the data sources into phpstorm. The datatools in phpstorm have the same feature set as datagrip (according to jetbrains support). Copy over the datasource.xml and datasource.local.xml when phpstrom isn't running. The 'kind of' part is that you will have to reenter any saved passwords.

Comment: In my case, I wanted to move project level data sources from phpStorm to DataGrip and this worked: `mv` `my-project/.idea/dataSources` `dataSources.*`  `~/Library/Preferences/DataGrip2017.2/projects/default/.idea/`

Comment: Could you write out the instructions? The gif doesn't show everything, takes a long time to go through, and if you miss it you have to wait for another round. Also, it's on a mac.

Comment: @Justin yes, sure: https://blog.jetbrains.com/datagrip/2018/05/21/copy-and-share-data-sources-in-datagrip/

Comment: for some weird reasons, I have a problem with this method. I am able to copy the existing source and it shows import from clipboard but doesn't do anything when I click the clipboard button.

Comment: @zinoadidi looks like a bug, please report it: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/DBE

Comment: Copy-paste is amazing!

Comment: Note that the copy/paste method only works once - if you have existing data sources, the paste won't work. So you should copy all the data sources in one go, and then paste into a project with no data sources. Finally set up passwords as needed, as they don't get copied across.

Answer (score 28):

You can do it easily via the clipboard, although it took me a while to figure it out:

1. in your source project, open the Database tool window, select the data sources you want to export, then right click / "Database Tools..." / "Copy Settings"
2. in your target project, open Database tool window, click on "+" then "Import from Clipboard"

Also works between DataGrip and IntelliJ.

**Addendum**
The wording has changed slightly in DataGrip 2018.2 EAP (or before), instead of "Copy Settings" it's now "Copy Data Source(s) to Clipboard", which reflects better what it does.

Comment: This is great for when I want to copy a data source between DataGrip projects locally.

Comment: It is good to know that "Import from Clipboard" button is not visible if your Clipboard is empty. So be sure that you copy the settings before.

Comment: True. The process is still unintuitive, I wish I could just Ctrl-C/Ctrl-V a Datasource from one project to another!

Comment: Easy, clean solution. Ctrl + Shift + A and search Database to easily open Database sidebar,   then hit the "+" and there you will find "Paste Source from Clipboard"

Answer (score 19):

DataGrip stores data sources on two different levels:

- **Project level**: together with project configuration files inside `.idea` subfolder of the project folder
- **IDE level**: stored in [IDE **config**](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519)/options directory.

**Project level** data source is available once you open the project.

To import/export **IDE level** Data Source use File | [Import/Export settings](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/exporting-and-importing-settings.html) action.

To move Data Source to IDE settings and back use corresponding action in Datasource Properties dialog (see screenshot) as shown here:
[image: Global / local datasource switch in datagrip]

Answer (score 4):

On my current version **2020.1** the projects are on:

```
 /System/Volumes/Data/Users/<USER_NAME>/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/DataGrip2020.1/projects/default/
```

A good way to find where is it store is just calling:

```
 find . -name "dataSources.xml"
```

It will find for that file everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

make the data source global and use export settings to export.
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/managing-data-sources.html#sharing-data-source-settings

Answer (score 0):

You can find all data sources at this path (change username and version):

> C:\Users\fouad.DataGrip2019.1\config\projects\default\.idea

Answer (score 0):

I recently discovered a really cool Mongodb plugin for IntelliJ and DataGrip called 'Mongo Expert' that helps users navigate the Mongodb database and work more efficiently. With support for Commandline MongDB Database Tools like mongoexpert, mongoimport, mongodump, and mongorestore, users can create and execute commands through easy-to-understand dialogues. You can download 'Mongo Expert' from the JetBrains Plugin Repository. I hope it will be useful for you too!

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/20761-mongo-expert

Answer (score 0):

DataGrip 2023.3.2 with New UI Enabled:

[image]